# MySQL InnoDB unrecoverable crash

Tags: mysql, innodb

Whenever I start MySQL server 5.1.33 or 5.1.40 (developers build) and try to read from one table the server crashes with this message in log files:

InnoDB: Error: (1500) Couldn't read the MAX(userFK) autoinc value from the index (PRIMARY).

I've upgraded to 5.1.40 per http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44030 but I still can't read from the table, so I cannot recover it. I've started the server with innodb_force_recovery=1 but that didn't help either, REPAIR, CHECK or SELECT or any other command just crashes the server.

How can I repair the table so that it is readable again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you either need to restore from a backup or pay Oracle lots of money. Sorry.

Comment: Or use another free database that supports transactions...like PostgreSQL or Firebird.  Both are based on mature code, and while *any* database can encounter problems, I seem to keep reading the same "MySQL imploded and my web server can't get up" stories over and over again.  Maybe it's a clue?

Comment: MySQL supports transactions and usually recovers from crashes. This error was very weird. I had to drop the table and restore the backup.

Comment: This is nothing to do with transactions. This is a corrupted data file.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [innodb-tools](http://code.google.com/p/innodb-tools/). maybe you'll have some luck with your data.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you need to restore from your latest backup.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the data is corrupted you may be able to select around it with a where clause.  You'll likely never recover all the data from the corrupted table but you may be able to back it up row by row.